# How can I extract an "extractEntityFromPostedJson" in Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod

After a bit of trial and error I managed to create the following function in Yesod to grab an object from a JSON POST, create an `EventFolder` entity, and save it to the database.

```
postAddEventFolderR :: Handler RepJson
postAddEventFolderR = do
    r <- waiRequest 
    v <- liftIO . runResourceT $ requestBody r $$ sinkParser json
    let v1 :: EventFolder
        v1 = case fromJSON v of
                 Success a -> a
                 Error s   -> error s
    runDB $ insert $ v1
    return $ RepJson $ toContent $ show v1
```

The test function looks like `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name":"test_folder"}' http://localhost:5000/AddEventFolder`.

The question is, well, first, is there a more concise way to write this function--it seems rather long-winded.  And second, how could I extract a function that generically creates an object from the JSON?  So I'd like to end up with something like

```
postAddEventFolderR = do
    v1 = extractEntityFromJsonPost (whatever params) :: EventFolder
    runDB $ insert $ v1
    return $ RepJson $ toContent $ show v1
```

Note I'm completely new to Haskell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the function you're looking for is [parseJsonBody_](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-json/1.0.0.1/doc/html/Yesod-Json.html#v%3aparseJsonBody_). Additionally, instead of using `toContent` and `show`, I think you'd want to use [jsonToRepJson](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-json/1.0.0.1/doc/html/Yesod-Json.html#v%3ajsonToRepJson). So all together, you can probably express your code as:

```
postAddEventFolderR = do
    v <- parseJsonBody_
    runDB $ insert (v :: EventFolder)
    jsonToRepJson v
```

Though I'm not entirely certain why you're responding with the data that the client just submitted.

Comment: Great, thanks.  If you don't mind I'll also link one of your repos here for a larger example.  https://github.com/snoyberg/yesod-js/blob/master/samples/todo.lhs

Comment: @ the response issue: It is customary to do one of three things when responding to a POST: to return the posted entry with any modifications that were made, to return some kind of "status OK" message, or to send a redirect response. @lobsterism is here opting for alternative 1; if you POST to `/folder/new` with `name`=`test_folder`, and the folder already exists, you can respond with `{"name":"test_folder (1)"}` to indicate that the resource `/folder/test_folder (1)` was created. Obviously, the code for that isn't implemented here.

Comment: Actually the response was just a placeholder. Still plenty to do. . .